# Mypy fails when using Werkzeug's abort() for throwing exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, mypy, werkzeug

When using flask.abort() (which ultimately throws an exception through Werkzeug), mypy fails because it can't see it will result in an exception:

```
error: Missing return statement
```

Is there a way to hint mypy that this will end in an exception so it should regard it as that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mypy needs the `typing.NoReturn` return type annotation on `abort()` to understand the situation. For that you need to install the separate `types-Werkzeug` package:

```
pip install types-Werkzeug
```

Comment: I just ran into the same issue and this worked for me. Hope it helps!